# A word meaning that something is "believed to be true by the majority, but most likely not true"

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a single word to describe something that is "believed to be true by the majority, but most likely not true". How could I say this?

Comment: Just a single word, or a phrases OK too?

Comment: a single word :)

Comment: @fixer1234's "misconception" suggestion is very good. P.S. There is never a need for a single word instead of a phrase, or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

If you can go with two words, **common misconception** is often used to describe that.  Wikipedia even has a dedicated page for [common misconceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_misconceptions), which it defines as "erroneous beliefs that are currently widely held".

Answer (score 0):

The word I was looking for when I ran across your question, which I’ve now found, is the word “factoid” Usually spoken as a “common factoid”